# How can I use a double relation to include the currentUser as criteria?

Tags: craft3, relations

I have a front-end form that allows registered users to edit content. In this case, it is a podcast. I have multiple podcasts that blog to different providers.

Here is how I am selecting the provider that belongs to the `currentUser`:

```
{% set provider = craft.entries()
    .section('provider').relatedTo({
        element: currentUser,
        field: 'contributors'
    }).one() %}
```

Works great. From there, here is how I am selecting the podcast that belongs to the current provider (selected above).

```
{% set podcast = craft.entries()
    .section('podcast').relatedTo({
        targetElement: provider,
        field: 'podcastProvider'
    }).one() %}
```

This works well, I am able to get the podcast and do whatever with it.

However, I'd also like to make a double check that this podcast belongs to the current provider - which belongs to the `currentUser`. Maybe that's overkill, I'd like to hear thoughts about that...

Here is what I am trying, but not having much luck.

```
{% set podcast = craft.entries()
    .section('podcast')
    .relatedTo(['and',
        {targetElement: provider, field: 'podcastProvider'},
        {targetElement: currentUser, field: 'provider.contributors'}
    ]).one() %}
```

`currentUser` is of course the user that is currently logged in. `contributors` is a `users` field that exists on the provider entry.

So, I was trying to make double-sure that the person who was logged in, not only belong to the provider, but the podcast they are editing belongs to the provider - that they (the currentUser) belongs to.

Or, is this completely overkill? Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: If `contributors` is a users field for the provider how is that field supposed to be related to a podcast? I don't really see any relation or ways how Craft should know what elements to fetch with your current setup

Comment: The podcast is related to the provider, which is related to the `currentUser`. Does that help? I've updated my question, I did not have my final query entered correctly.

Comment: I thought so but Craft can't search for entries that are related to a certain other related element. You can't skip relation levels via related to param without creating custom joins and rules via sql

Comment: Fair enough - thank you very much for your feedback! What I have works well, so perhaps it's overkill anyway.